# Eigenvalues of an irreducible Hessenberg Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This was a problem from a homework several weeks ago. I've got a test coming up, and I'm still not sure I understand it. The professor mentioned it having something to do with the $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ submatrix having full rank, but I'm still unsure about it.

Let $H \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ be an irreducible Hessenberg matrix, i.e.,
$$
H=\begin{bmatrix}
h_ {11} &  h_ {12}&  \cdots &  h_ {1,n-1}& h_ {1n}\\ 
h_ {21} &  h_ {22 }&  \cdots & h_ {2,n-1} & h_ {2n}\\ 
0 &  h_ {32} &  \cdots & h_ {3,n-1} & h_ {3n}\\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\ 
0 &  0&  \cdots &  h_ {n,n-1}&h_ {nn} 
\end{bmatrix}$$
with $h_{i+1,i} \ne 0$ for $ i=1:n-1$. Prove that the eigenvalues of $H$ are geometrically simple; that is, $d(\lambda)= 1, \forall \lambda \in \sigma(H)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $Hv=tv$, then $(H-tI)v=0$. In this matrix the block obtained by erasing the first row and the last column is diagonal with nonzero diagonal. So the rank of $H-tI$ is $n-1$, which tells us that its kernel has dimension $1$. This works for any eigenvalue $t$, so all eigenvalues have geometric multiplicity one.

Comment: So the rank of $H−tI$  is $n−1$ , which tells us that its kernel has dimension $1$. Why this is correct?

Comment: Because of the [Rank-Nullity Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem).